# AWS KMS Decrypt call returns InvalidCiphertextException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-kms

I am currently using AWS Cognito's `customEmailSender` trigger to send my emails. In the function event, I get the code and it is encrypted using the KMS key I created in CDK and passed into my Cognito UserPool. I was attempting to decrypt the code to send it to the user, but I keep getting an `InvalidCiphertextException`. This is how my Java function looks:

```
private String decryptCode(String code) {
  KmsClient kmsClient = KmsClient.builder().build();

  byte[] encryptedData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(code);

  DecryptRequet decryptRequest = DecryptRequest.builder()
    .ciphertextBlob(SdkBytes.fromByteArray(encryptedData))
    .keyId(keyArn)
    .build();

  DecryptResponse decryptResponse = kmsClient.decrypt(decryptRequest);

  ByteBuffer plaintext = decryptResponse.plaintext().asByteBuffer();

  String decryptedData = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(plaintext).toString();

  log.info("DecryptedData {}", decryptedData);

  kmsClient.close();

  return decryptedData;
}
```

When this function gets called I get that error. I decided to try and run the decrypt from the cli to see if that worked, so I ran this with the same error:

`aws kms decrypt --ciphertext-blob fileb://<(echo 'encrypted-data' | base64 -d) --key-id arn:aws:kms:<region>:<accountid>:key/<id>`

Unfortunately, the error doesn't provide any useful information. I already checked to make sure that the lambda function has the `kms:Decrypt` and `kms:DescribeKey` policies.

I had tried with a NodeJS function to see if that would work at one point and it actually would work with this code:

```
const b64 = require('base64-js');
const encryptionSdk = require('@aws-crypto/client-node');
const { decrypt } = encryptionSdk.buildClient(
  encryptionSdk.CommitmentPolicy.REQUIRE_ENCRYPT_ALLOW_DECRYPT
);
const generatorKeyId = process.env.KEY_ALIAS;
const keyIds = [process.env.KEY_ARN];
const keyring = new encryptionSdk.KmsKeyringNode({ generatorKeyId, keyIds });

if (event.request.code) {
  const { plaintext } = await decrypt( keyring, b64.toByteArray(event.request.code) );
  return plaintext.toString();
}
```

Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: It looks like your JS code is using the AWS encryption SDK, which is not what your java code is doing. Find the Java equivalent here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/java.html